# making one list a dictionary with elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
    a = [
{"price":["9","20"],
    "name":["samsung", "somsung2"]},
    {"price":["40","50"],
    "name":["iphone", "iphone2"]}

    ]


for x in range(len(a)):
    for c in a[x].values():
        ...
```

how can i do to dictionary to show like : `{"9":"samsung", "20":"somsung2", "40":"iphone", "50":"iphone2"}`

Comment: What if two phones have the same price…?

Comment: maybe `{'samsung':9, ...etc}` is better, as there will be no duplicates, as @deceze noticed?

Comment: add in the dictionary anyways, cause they wont have same names, names are unique.

Comment: @Nika110 .. *but what if the have the same price*? Then you can only have one phone

Comment: To be clear: if both `ophone` and `ophone2` cost `42`, your dictionary will look like… `{42: 'ophone', 42: 'ophone2'}`…?! And when you access `d[42]` you'll get… what exactly? (Hint: that's not how it works.)

Comment: yep, so should i change keys to solve it?

Comment: *You tell us* what you're tryinna do here…

Comment: when i acccess dictionary with price can it show all items with the same price?

Comment: Then your dict structure needs to be something like `{42: ['ophone', 'ophone2'], ...}`.

Comment: yep, i got it, just realized about duplicates that would destroy my dictionary, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

All you need is something like:

```
result = {}
for d in a:
    for k,v in zip(d['price'], d['name']):
        result[k] = v
```

Or just:

```
{k:v for d in a for k,v in zip(d['price'], d['name'])}
```

But you almost certainly don't want to do this. If there are duplicate prices, you will lose a name. Consider the extreme case where all the prices are the same, for illustration purposes:

```
In [1]: a = [{'price': ['20', '20'], 'name': ['samsung', 'somsung2']},
   ...:  {'price': ['20', '20'], 'name': ['iphone', 'iphone2']}]

In [2]: {k:v for d in a for k,v in zip(d['price'], d['name'])}
Out[2]: {'20': 'iphone2'}
```

So instead, use a *dictionary of lists*:

```
In [6]: a = [{'price': ['9', '20'], 'name': ['samsung', 'somsung2']},
   ...:  {'price': ['20', '50'], 'name': ['iphone', 'iphone2']}]

In [7]: result = {}

In [8]: for d in a:
   ...:     for k,v in zip(d['price'], d['name']):
   ...:         result.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
   ...:

In [9]: result
Out[9]: {'9': ['samsung'], '20': ['somsung2', 'iphone'], '50': ['iphone2']}
```

Comment: yep, thats i was looking for but now i realize about duplicates and its not good idea, thanks anyways.

Comment: @Nika110 use a *dict of lists*, see the update to my answer

Comment: yep, thats i was looking for, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```py
dict = [
    {"price":["9","20"], "name":["samsung", "somsung2"]},
    {"price":["40","50"], "name":["iphone", "iphone2"]}
]

formattedDict = {}

for dictElementIndex in range(len(dict)):
    for insideElementIndex in range(len(dict[dictElementIndex]["price"])):
        formattedDict[dict[dictElementIndex]["price"][insideElementIndex]] = dict[dictElementIndex]["name"][insideElementIndex] 
        print(dict[dictElementIndex]["price"][insideElementIndex] + ":" + dict[dictElementIndex]["name"][insideElementIndex])

print(formattedDict)
```

#### output

```
9:samsung
20:somsung2
40:iphone
50:iphone2
{'9': 'samsung', '20': 'somsung2', '40': 'iphone', '50': 'iphone2'}
```

Comment: don't loop over ranges. And this isn't the output the OP wanted.

Comment: It makes the dict that you want, am i right? @Nika110

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach, Assuming product names will always be unique.

```
data = [{"price": ["9", "20"], "name":["samsung", "somsung2"]},
        {"price": ["40", "50"], "name":["iphone", "iphone2"]}]

result = {}
for items in data:
    for index, product in enumerate(items['name']):
        result[product] = items['price'][index]

print(result)
```

Output

```
{'samsung': '9', 'somsung2': '20', 'iphone': '40', 'iphone2': '50'}
```

Don't forget to do a validation check for following :-

- Incase the names and price length are different.
- The name already exists (Duplicate name).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
data = {}
for item in a:
    data = {**data,**dict(zip(item['price'], item['name']))}
```

Comment: `data|dict(zip(item['price'], item['name']))` is inefficient. Use `data |= dict(zip(item['price'], item['name'])`

Comment: Right, it's still unecessarily does extra work. I don't find it any more readable than using `data.update(dict(zip(...)))` and it introduces potentially quadratic behavior when this should be linear.

Comment: Then dont use it :), its just another approach that might seem nice to some people , btw i upvoted your answer cuz it is good.. had no intention to replace it